# What is the best pattern for accepting funds to a program?

Tags: anchor, program

Should I create a separate PDA account that is solely dedicated to handling funds or should I handle funds in the same PDA account that is storing state about my program? Are there any security implications in either case? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

PDA are address's which does not have any private keys and your program has control over how to use it and it completely depends on your funds transfer logic if you are transferring SPL tokens then in most cases your PDA is the authority of the token account which holds the tokens. for SOL you have to be a bit careful and make sure the account rent does not get's modified when u modify the amount of SOL that account/PDA holds. I would suggest for best practises you can read through some of the audited open source programs in the ecosystem